# Selector for one tag directly followed by another tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

This selects all `<B>` tags directly *preceded* by `<A>` tags:

```
A+B {
    /* styling */
}
```

What is the selector for all `<A>` tags directly *followed* by `<B>` tags?

Here's sample HTML fitting my question:

```
<a>some text</a>
<b>some text</b>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can’t in css.

**Edit:** To be a bit more helpful, if you use for example jQuery (a JavaScript library), you can use [`.prev()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev).

Comment: it seams the only solution's using JavaScript

Comment: Thanks jeroen!  That fixed my issue.  Since my "A" floats left and "B" floats right, it didn't matter what order I put the markup in.

Answer (score 58):

Do you mean to style A given that it has a B element directly inside or followed? Like this:

```
<A>
    <B>
    </B>
</A>

// OR

<A>
</A>
<B>
</B>
```

You can't do such a thing in CSS (yet). Eric Meyer states that this kind of selector has been discussed quite a few times on the CSS mailing list, and isn’t doable. Dave Hyatt, one of the core WebKit developers, comments with a good explanation of why it can’t be done.

Check out: [Shaun Inman's blog post](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors) and the [comment by Eric Meyer](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors#comment_3911).
[David Hyatt weighs in](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors#comment_3940), too.

Comment: i mean the second one, i understand the issue thank you nick :)

Comment: The links are unfortunately broken as of now

Answer (score 29):

You can now use the `:has()` css selector ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-has)):

```
    .first:has(+ .second) {
        background: #ff0000;
    }
```

That can be read: select all elements with class ".first" that are followed by element of class ".second"

```
    <div class="first">Foo</div>
    <div class="second">Bar</div>
```

Comment: So it was doable after all :) Really GREAT. So helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

You can ONLY do the converse: This selects all  tags directly preceded by  tags.

This is logically equivalent to your request.

I often use this to style a row of many checkboxes with labels

CSS:

```
label+input {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

DOM:

```
<input id="a" name="a" type="checkbox"/><label for="a">...</label>
<input id="b" name="b" type="checkbox"/><label for="b">...</label>
<input id="c" name="c" type="checkbox"/><label for="c">...</label>
```

Comment: I think you meant to type "input+label" in the CSS so that the margin-left is applied to the label.

Comment: @CAK2 - I think he meant it right. By doing `label+input` the margin is applied to all `input` elements **starting from the second one**. It is a creative way to create space among them but not at the beginning or at then end of the row. In this case, it is equivalent to `input:not(:first-child)`.

Answer (score 8):

Although it's not very handy, nowadays you could achieve this behavior by reversing the order of your elements both when you generate the HTML and by applying the CSS rules: `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column-reverse`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.b ~ .a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="a">A 3</li>
    <li class="c">C 2</li>
    <li class="c">C 1</li>
    <li class="b">B 1</li>
    <li class="a">A 2</li>
    <li class="a">A 1</li>
</ul>
```

Also, if you have 2 or more inline elements, you could achieve it by applying `float: right`, as they will be displayed in reverse order:

```css
ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.b ~ .a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="a">A 3</li>
    <li class="c">C 2</li>
    <li class="c">C 1</li>
    <li class="b">B 1</li>
    <li class="a">A 2</li>
    <li class="a">A 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This hack is likely to hurt accessibility, because the order of the elements in the DOM should be logical. People who navigate with keyboard and people who use screen readers will navigate elements in the DOM order, not taking into account the flexblox tweak.