# How to correctly attach 'arrowed' block to the input above

Tags: forms, margin, css

[image]

As you can see, I got it right when the list inside my block has only one row, but it's wrong when the list is bigger.

Since I can't select only those inputs followed by errors (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132366/a-that-followed-by-b-css-selector)), my current solution is a negative margin-top:

```
.errorlist {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: -1em;
    max-width: 30em;
    min-width: 10em;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Arrow: */
.errorlist:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 100%;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(205, 10, 10) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.errorlist li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="required">
     <p>
         <label for="id_username">Nombre de usuario:</label> 
         <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" id="id_username">
     </p>
     <ul class="errorlist ui-state-error">
         <li>Este campo es obligatorio.</li>
         <li>Este campo es obligatorio.</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: I've noticed that only the 2nd `<li>` is moving the block. I can add as many as I want and the block doesn't slide updwards any more.

Comment: wouldn't adding another list <li></li> make a 2nd row?

Comment: @Keith yes, it does, but it makes the <ul> block slide a bit upwards (the first input)

Comment: not sure if this is the case, but probably because of the style <li> has a padding of .5 so everytime you input a <li> line it will bump up the list a little.

Comment: if removing the whitespace or the html5 version doesnot works, just use an auto height div with desired padding to display your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the position of `ul.errorlist` using the `top` property rather than `margin-top`, the `li` elements will stay put, and you can tweak the `top`

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/bqxdj/

```
.errorlist {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1em;
    top: -1.5em;
    max-width: 30em;
    min-width: 10em;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: It works!, apparently. Any idea why only the 2nd `li` was moving the block?

Comment: Honestly, no. It has something to do with the vertical alignment of inline block elements, and height calculations, but i ran out of patience to nail it down. I did learn more about border collapse than i ever wanted to know though. hah.

Answer (score 0):

list tags automatically adds a whitespace.
To get rid of this try:

```
     <li>Este campo es obligatorio.</li><li>Este campo es obligatorio.</li>
```

or if you are safe with HTML5,

```
     <li>Este campo es obligatorio.
     <li>Este campo es obligatorio.
```

remove the  end tag.

Hope this works.

EDIT: remove the margin-top:-1em
http://jsfiddle.net/ymSKX/

Comment: :/ Sorry but the code is generated exactly as `<li>Este campo es obligatorio.</li><li>Este campo es obligatorio.</li>`. I changed it manually in my post to make it easier to read.

Comment: try the html5 version then

Comment: Done, it didn't change anything either :(  . I will try with the div now, adding the `height:auto` to the ul would have the same effect?

Comment: If I change the `display` to `block` the background expands to the whole page width, and without the negative margin the arrow doesn't actually touch the input :/ http://jsfiddle.net/ymSKX/3/

Comment: you will have to set margin-left accordingly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33795/discussion-between-madeyedexter-and-adrian-lopez)