# Update header color based on page content

Tags: html, css

I have a website I'm building with a header that is going to be present on all pages.  However, I'd like the header to change background color depending on div that follows the header.  Is there a way that I can accomplish this with just 1 css file?

```css
header {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>header</h1>
</header>
<div id="page1">
  <p>page content</p>
</div>
```

Here's an example of a page that might be on my website.  Let's say I have another page where the page has an id "page2."  How can I dynamically have the background updated based on what the id of the div is?  Is this possible?  If not, is there an easy workaround to accomplish the desired result?

Comment: I would recommend adding a page-specific class to your header and styling the various classes.

Comment: @Rafael thank you for the input.  The issue is that I am building the site with Django and my header is part of the base template, so I'd then have to find a way to update the classes for each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that just with css, you will need something like `.prev()` in jquery to achieve that. [Related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1132370/8950658)

Comment: Thank you for the direction and for pointing me to this thread.  I'll need to learn some jquery!

Comment: Yup!  I have confirmed, this was exactly what I needed!  Thank you!